# Dynamic subdirectories in a cmake build

Tags: cmake

I'm setting up a Cmake build environment for a project I have inherited. I have a core repository that creates a target that can load 'plugins' (dll targets). I want to keep each plugin in its own repository (each represents a specific hardware platform and should be maintained separately).

I have a directory, called "Plugins" where these repository folders will be cloned as needed.

How do I cause the CMakeLists.txt in the "Plugins" folder to add all plugin folders without adding an explicit add_subdirectory for each plugin?

My goal is to allow a build script that provides out of source configuration and debug/release targets to also allow platform targets that will checkout the repositories for the platform(s) selected by the user, configure, and build as requested. This piece is the only one I'm not sure how to set up.

Comment: ***How do I cause the CMakeLists.txt in the "Plugins" folder to add all plugin folders without adding an explicit add_subdirectory for each plugin?*** I use a CMake macro to get the list of subdirectories (using file GLOB) then a for loop to add_subdirectory()

Comment: Can you provide an example as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

When I do this for example programs I have a `CMake` macro that enumerates the subdirectories of the current folder:

```
#########################################################################################

macro(SUBDIRLIST result curdir)
  FILE(GLOB children RELATIVE ${curdir} ${curdir}/*)
  SET(dirlist "")
  FOREACH(child ${children})
    IF(IS_DIRECTORY ${curdir}/${child})
        SET(dirlist ${dirlist} ${child})
    ENDIF()
  ENDFOREACH()
  SET(${result} ${dirlist})
endmacro()
```

Then with this macro I create the following CMakeLists.txt in the folder that has the subdirectories:

```
SUBDIRLIST(SUBDIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

FOREACH(subdir ${SUBDIRS})
    ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(${subdir})
ENDFOREACH()
```

When `CMake` generates using this parent folder it will automatically add each folder it contains using add_subidrectory()

Comment: That looks almost identical to this code I ran into earlier.
https://github.com/gwaldron/osgearth/issues/608
Except they add directories to the list with append rather than set.
I was hoping for a built-in operation, but I suppose I can just unpack the process.

Comment: There is a chance we got the code from the same source. The macros file I have is 5+ years old.

Comment: I did something similar but unrolled, and I added a check for the presence of CmakeLists.txt in each subdirectory before the add_subdirectory() call, as the new projects are git submodules, all the plugin directories I need checked are strictly optional, submodules are access gated by gitlab permissions, the folders will always be present even if empty, and the application must build even if no plugins are present. I will update the answer as time allows.